# Cell spacing in div table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like the there to be 4 or so pixel space between each cell. I'd like the grey header to have the spaces rather then a block of grey. I tried playing around ( background-clip:padding-box; padding: 14px; margin etc) but couldn't figure out how to put a few pixels between cells in a div table. How do I do this?

Demo of problem http://jsfiddle.net/EJBnm/

```
<div class="TableBox">
    <div>
        <div>Head</div> <div>Bigger Head</div> <div>Medium</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>First</div> <div>Second</div> <div>Third</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>First</div> <div>Second</div> <div>Third</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>First</div> <div>Second</div> <div>Third</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.TableBox {display: table;}
.TableBox > div {display: table-row; border-spacing: 5px}
.TableBox > div >div {display: table-cell;  margin: 4px;}
.TableBox > div:nth-child(even){ color: red; }
.TableBox > div:nth-child(1){  background-color: #666666; color:white; border-spacing: 15px; background-clip:padding-box; padding: 14px; margin:0 20px}
```

Comment: Use a table for tabular data!!!!!!

Comment: There ya go. Why the hell use a bunch of divs? Tables are good at one thing... making tables. Which is what you are making.

Comment: A grid of logically-associated data is a table, so it is completely appropriate to use the TABLE tag.

Comment: Based on all these comments I wonder why `display: table` exists...

Comment: I would just like to add that sometimes (rarely) there is a good reason for creating a table with divs.  Like for example if you want the layout of a simple table to create a popup menu (with one column for an icon and the second column for text), but you don't want the styles from the parent table to cascade down to the menu.  Creating the menu with divs (in table format) is an easy workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `border-spacing: 4px;` to your `.TableBox` class instead of your `<tr>`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJBnm/1/

Comment: @Leeish: see my comment to main question but... whats wrong with what I am doing? (Is the answer everything?) -edit- is the answer it hard to find reference to simple things like spacing...

Comment: @BruteCode... you are forcing divs to make a table, which is crazy because HTML has table functionality. Why wouldn't you use it? Developers like you are the reason I have to edit lines of `span` elements instead of just a table for tabular data.

Comment: @Leeish: Why do you have to edit lines of span? Is it because you don't know the css to do what you want? ;) (i'll admit I didn't know what this was and googling gave me horrible results)

Comment: Basically because our old developer had to use tons of lines of CSS just to make the spans act like tables. Yes, its very difficult to make the CSS do what you want when forcing a span to do something that in my opinion it was never designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent (or white border) instead of margin: http://jsfiddle.net/jfsWc/

```
.TableBox > div >div {display: table-cell;  border:4px solid transparent}
```