# Why does `display: table` exist?

Tags: html, html-table

In my other question [cell spacing in div table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167943/) everyone said tables are better then div tables and one mentioned there is no benefit div tables have over html tables. I'm confused, why was `display: table` introduce and whats the point of it if its terrible?

Comment: I would postulate that it allows the developer to achieve the traditional table layout behavior without incorrectly using an element with semantic meaning. In other words, it is semantically wrong to use a `table` for layout; it's arguably also wrong to *not* use a table for tabular data. `display: table` lets you achieve the layout without the (incorrect) semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of any other consideration about whether it's better to use tables or divs in any given situation, the reason `display:table` exists (and related `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`) is because CSS is supposed to be able to render any arbitrary HTML (or even XML) into the desired layout, without needing any styling effects to be hard-coded into the browser.

The standard `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc elements have a significant amount of default styling applied; and behave quite differently from other elements in a number of ways. `display:table` replicates those different behaviours.

Modern browsers can therefore simply use `display:table` as the default style for the `table` element, rather than having to have hard-coded table-specific rendering built into the engine, as was the case with older browsers.

Answer (score 5):

A *display table* behaves a certain way with regards to cell spacing and stretching. This behavior is difficult to reproduce using other means. An HTML `<table>` element should only be used for *tabular data* though (think Excel spreadsheets). So one is the display behavior, the other is the semantic (meaningful) markup. You may want to use one without the other, that's why they're two different things.

If you have tabular data, mark it up using `<table>` and get the table display behavior for free. If you have something which really isn't tabular data but you want to display it with the behavior of a table, slap a CSS table display behavior on it.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of whether or not to use one or another is based more around the use of tables for data rather than for layout. A good rule of thumb is to use a table when you're actually trying to use a "table" of data.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that HTML markup (`<table>`) should describe what content *is*, while CSS (`display:table`) describes what the content should *look like*. They are not the same.

You can use it on non-table elements, but `display:table` is the only proper choice when you want to set an actual table's display property.

Here's an easily understandable example:

```
<div class="my-tables">
    <table>...</table>
    <table>...</table>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

```
.my-tables table {
    display:none; /* hide all the tables */
}
```

How do you *show* one of the tables, say the first one?

```
.my-tables table:first-child {
    /* display:block; not quite... */
    display:table; /* There it is! */
}
```

Tables are the right tool for marking up tabular content. Tables *just* for layout is a misuse of the tag otherwise. Using `<p>` or `<fieldset>` for layout would be equally wrong.